# WP global invariant

Tags: frama-c

I have installed the latest frama-c release (phosphorus) on Linux, 
and tried to define a global invariant, but got the message that is 
not supported yet by WP.
What is the status  about that ?
Is there a documentation about what is supported in ACSL language ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ACSL features supported by Frama-C's kernel are described in the ACSL implementation manual that is available for each release. For Phosphorus, it is [here](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl-implementation-Phosphorus-20170501.pdf). If something is not supported by the kernel, it will of course not be supported by any plug-in either.

On the other hand, plug-ins tend to only support a given subset of what is available in the kernel. It is normally up to the plug-in documentation to precisely define this subset, but in the case of the [WP manual](http://frama-c.com/download/wp-manual-Phosphorus-20170501.pdf), this seems to be missing. This probably ought to be considered as a bug.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, that is several years I follow Frama-C and noticed that global invariant was never supported.